# Javascript looping objects

Tags: javascript

I need to make a function called onlyTruthy that takes in an object, loops through all its properties, and removes any that are falsy. Then return the object that was passed in. But I'm confused on how to make it truthy or falsey. This is what I have so far.

```
function onlyTruthy (val) {
    for (var key in val) {
        if (val.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            alert(key + " -> " + val[key]);
        }
    }
    return val;
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think it is better to create a new variable to hold only true values of the existing object as I shown below:

```
var yourOldObject;  /* some data in it */
var newObject = onlyTruthy(yourOldObject);  /* newObject variable holds only true values now */

function onlyTruthy (val) {
    var newObj = {};
    for (var key in val) {
        if (val.hasOwnProperty(key) && val[key]) {
            newObj[key] = val[key];
        }
    }
    return newObj;
}
```

Comment: can the data just be numbers? or words? or mixed?

Comment: @OsmerhChichia can you give me an example?

Comment: @OsmerhChichia if my answer was helpful to you please mark it as answer.

Comment: @JordanDavis can you please explain?

Comment: @Mr_Green well why do you need to create a new object and copy all `property:values` which pass `true` over to it. Why don't you just modify the existing array which gets passed to the function and return the modified array.

Comment: @JordanDavis In both cases, I will do the loop. I still can't see why I shouldn't do this?

Comment: @Mr_Green its not a big deal just not as efficient as it could be, it's like replicating an object for no reason... a variable is a container already why don't you just modify the existing container rather than creating another.

Comment: @OsmerhChichia please check Jordan comments above for considering performance.

Answer (score 2):

I think you could use `!` to check whether it is falsy and delete operator to delete the property

```
function onlyTruthy(val) {
  for (var key in val) {
    if (val.hasOwnProperty(key) && !val[key]) {
      delete val[key];
    }
  }
  return val;
}
```

Comment: Why `return val;` inside `for`? _that takes in an object, loops through all its properties, and removes any that are falsy_

Comment: @Tushar there was a bracket missing, didn't check properly while adding it

Comment: I edited the original question to add the missing closing bracket.

Comment: @jkdev you can't alter the code provided by OP. You should just format it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the simplest and most efficient:

```
var car = {
    make: "bmw",
    model: "328i",
    year: "2012",
    color: null,
    mileage: undefined,
    doors: false,   
    cylinders: ""
};


onlyTruthy=(o)=>{
    Object.keys(o).forEach((p)=>(!o[p])?delete o[p]:null);
    return o;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

you can simply replace object  with your own Object (which has some propperties)

```
    for (var property in object) {
if (object.hasOwnProperty(property)) {
     alert( ' the Key is  : '+ property + ' And the value is : ' + object[property]);
}
}
```

you can change the object by your instance of ur class or any  other Object